# Delete all posts from WordPress except latest X posts

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

On a project I require to keep only 10 latest posts on website and auto delete all other posts. So I came up with this function which triggers on post publish/update and I used `offset` parameter to exclude latest 10 items.

```
function wpse_auto_delete_posts( $post_ID ) {
  global $post;

  $delete_posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'offset' => 10, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
  foreach ( $delete_posts as $delete_post ) : setup_postdata( $delete_post );
    wp_delete_post( $delete_post->ID, true );
  endforeach;
  wp_reset_postdata();

}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse_auto_delete_posts' );
```

But it appears, `offset` didn't work here with `'posts_per_page' => -1` and it keeps deleting all posts. I thought of using Date query but it will also not work too because new posts are created very frequently.

Is there any way to select all posts except latest 10 or 5. So WordPress can process them and keep latest X posts.

Comment: Good question that have me hooked. I wonder how `posts_per_page=-1` influence offset as offset is used to calculate pagination in queries. `get_posts` also legally breaks pagination, so it would be interesting to see how this all influence the offset parameter ;-)

Comment: Yeh I have been trying to work on it from last couple of hours but could not find any way. Although it sounds very easy to achieve. :-P I kind of knew `offset` won't work but tried it anyway.

Comment: I have an idea, just need to test it out

Comment: The fact that get_posts() of query.php strictly defines the relationhip between `posts_per_page` and `nopaging`. I suggest a good solution here would be to overwrite/filter `post_clauses`. What do you think?

Comment: @IgnatB. `posts_per_page` needed to be overwritten and below solution (of setting this to higher number) by Pieter works perfectly. Although thank you for trying out and for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `offset` parameter is ignored with `posts_per_page` set to `-1` in `WP_Query`. If you look at the source code in the `WP_Query` class, `posts_per_page=-1` sets `nopaging` to true.

```
if ( !isset($q['nopaging']) ) {
    if ( $q['posts_per_page'] == -1 ) {
        $q['nopaging'] = true;
    } else {
        $q['nopaging'] = false;
    }
}
```

This in turn will not append the `LIMIT` to the SQL query (*`empty($q['nopaging'] === false` which fail the conditional statement*) meaning that the whole pagination/offset is ignored and all posts are returned regardless

```
if ( empty($q['nopaging']) && !$this->is_singular ) {
    $page = absint($q['paged']);
    if ( !$page )
        $page = 1;

    if ( empty($q['offset']) ) {
        $pgstrt = absint( ( $page - 1 ) * $q['posts_per_page'] ) . ', ';
    } else { // we're ignoring $page and using 'offset'
        $q['offset'] = absint($q['offset']);
        $pgstrt = $q['offset'] . ', ';
    }
    $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $pgstrt . $q['posts_per_page'];
}
```

I think the best workaround here is to make use of normal PHP (*[`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)*)after getting all the posts. You want to get only post ID's here as `wp_delete_post` is quite expensive to run and only really need the post ID, so we don't need any other post info.

In short, your query will look like this: (***NOTE:*** This is all untested and needs PHP 5.4+)

```
add_action( 'publish_post', function ( $post_ID ) 
{
    $args = [
        'nopaging' => true,
        'fields'   => 'ids'
    ];
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    // Make sure that we have post ID's returned
    if ( $posts_array ) {
        // Get all post ids after the 10th post using array_slice
        $delete_posts = array_slice( $posts_array, 10 );
        // Make sure that we actually have post ID's in the $delete_posts array
        if ( $delete_posts ) {
            foreach ( $delete_posts as $delete_post )
                wp_delete_post( $delete_post, true );
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Just before I forget, you can also define `posts_per_page` as an unlikely integer value instead of `-1`. This will also work with your code with the `offset` parameter set

Comment: +1 for setting the `posts_per_page` to some high number. Actually assuming the site starts with zero posts it can even be 2 as there will never be more then 11 posts.

Comment: @MarkKaplun the assumption here is, what happens if the site starts of with a 1000 posts. After an initial run or two, you are correct in the assumption that there will never be more than 11 posts :-)

Comment: My assumption is that it is not hard to manually delete X posts ;) and it is easier then writing the code to delete such a big amount as at some point you might run out of PHP memory, MYSQL memory or php execution time limit.

Comment: WOW @Pieter, `'posts_per_page' => '1000'` works great. I didn't tried out other solution you posted but I am sure it will work too. Thanks,

Comment: @MarkKaplun Not going to delete 1000s of post each time but 20-30 maximum so there will not be any issue of memory. Only requirement was that it must work automatically (will use cron for that) and should keep latest 5-10 posts.

Comment: @Roberthue glad it worked. I actually posted the first solution as an alternative, I only realized after posting that I forgot to post the easy solution whereby you just define posts_per_page as an unlikely integer. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `'nopaging' => true` and `'posts_per_page' => -1` behaves the same. This parameters are cancelling the `LIMIT` clause of MySQL request made by your WP.

> offset (int) - number of post to displace or pass over. Warning:
>   Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and
>   breaks pagination (Click here for a workaround). **The 'offset'
>   parameter is ignored when 'posts_per_page'=>-1 (show all posts) is
>   used.**

Considering the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4651990) and their recommendation, you can use a large number for `posts_per_page` parameter, leaving offset as it is.

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`

Comment: I want to select all posts except latest 10. Not the other way around.

Comment: Please check. Sorry for missunderstanding, Hope this would helps.